# Python call my AWS lambda from code with boto3 error

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

In my project i have to create a py that call a lambda function passing body parameters, i write this code:

```
import boto3
import json
import base64

client = boto3.client(‘lambda’)
d = {'calID': '92dqiss5bg87etcqeeamlmob2g@group.calendar.google.com', 'datada': '2017-12-22T16:40:00+01:00', 'dataa': '2017-12-22T17:55:00+01:00', 'email': 'example@hotmail.com'}
s = json.dump(d)
s64 = base64.b64encode(s.encode('utf-8'))

response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:13737373737:function:test',
    InvocationType='RequestResponse',
    LogType='None',
    ClientContext='None',
    Payload=s64
)
```

but when response run this error is generated:

> InvalidRequestContentException: An error occurred (InvalidRequestContentException) when calling the Invoke operation: Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token 'eyJjYWxJRCI6ICI5MmRxaXNzNWJnODdldGNxZWVhbWxtb2IyZ0Bncm91cC5jYWxlbmRhci5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwgImRhdGFkYSI6ICIyMDE3LTEyLTIyVDE2OjQwOjAwKzAxOjAwIiwgImRhdGFhIjogIjIwMTctMTItMjJUMTc6NTU6MDArMDE6MDAiLCAiZW1haWwiOiAibHVjYV9ncmV6eml4eEBob3RtYWlsLmNvbSJ9': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
>    at [Source: [B@4587098d; line: 1, column: 481]

what this mean?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can simply do `Payload=json.dumps(d)`. Nothing else is needed

Comment: Hi, if i use d the response is : ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Payload, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object

Comment: how about `s` :P

Comment: Sorry, yes. It was meant to be `json.dumps`. Edited the previous comment as well. Please also see https://github.com/cleesmith/boto3_test/blob/master/invoke.py#L42

Comment: if i use s (json.dumps(d)) code return : InvalidRequestContentException: An error occurred (InvalidRequestContentException) when calling the Invoke operation: Client context must be a valid Base64-encoded JSON object.

Comment: and with `json.dump(d)` or `Payload=s`?

Comment: InvalidRequestContentException: An error occurred (InvalidRequestContentException) when calling the Invoke operation: Client context must be a valid Base64-encoded JSON object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is because of the following parameter:

```
ClientContext='None',
```

From [the docs](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke):

> #### ClientContext (string) --
>
> Using the `ClientContext` you can pass client-specific information to
>   the Lambda function you are invoking. You can then process the client
>   information in your Lambda function as you choose through the context
>   variable. For an example of a `ClientContext` JSON, see [PutEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/latest/ug/PutEvents.html)
>   in the Amazon Mobile Analytics API Reference and User Guide .
>
> The ClientContext JSON must be base64-encoded and has a maximum size
>   of 3583 bytes.

You do not need the `ClientContext` parameter here at all. Simply invoke as follows:

```
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:13737373737:function:test',
    LogType='None',
    Payload=json.dumps(d)
)
```